# How does one read TensorBoard histograms for a 1D example in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I made the simplest 1D example for TensorBoard (tracking the minimization of a quadratic) but I get plots that don't make sense to me and I can't figure out why. Is it my own implementation or is TensorBoard buggy?

Here are the plots:

HISTOGRAM:

[image]

Usually I think of histograms as bar graphs that encode probability distributions (or frequency counts). I assume that the y-axis say the values and the x-axis the count? Since my numbers of steps is 120 that seemed reasonable guess.

and Scalar plot:

[image]

why is there a strange line going through my plots?

The code that produced it (you should be able to copy paste it and run it):

```
## run cmd to collect model: python playground.py --logdir=/tmp/playground_tmp
## show board on browser run cmd: tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/playground_tmp
## browser: http://localhost:6006/

import tensorflow as tf

# x variable
x = tf.Variable(10.0,name='x')
# b placeholder (simualtes the "data" part of the training)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# make model (1/2)(x-b)^2
xx_b = 0.5*tf.pow(x-b,2)
y=xx_b

learning_rate = 1.0
# get optimizer
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
# gradient variable list = [ (gradient,variable) ]
gv = opt.compute_gradients(y,[x])
# transformed gradient variable list = [ (T(gradient),variable) ]
decay = 0.9 # decay the gradient for the sake of the example
# apply transformed gradients
tgv = [ (decay*g, v) for (g,v) in gv] #list [(grad,var)]
apply_transform_op = opt.apply_gradients(tgv)

# track value of x
x_scalar_summary = tf.scalar_summary("x", x)
x_histogram_sumarry = tf.histogram_summary('x_his', x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    tensorboard_data_dump = '/tmp/playground_tmp'
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(tensorboard_data_dump, sess.graph)

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    epochs = 120
    for i in range(epochs):
        b_val = 1.0 #fake data (in SGD it would be different on every epoch)

        # applies the gradients
        [summary_str_apply_transform,_] = sess.run([merged,apply_transform_op], feed_dict={b: b_val})
        writer.add_summary(summary_str_apply_transform, i)
```

Comment: I've asked a similar flavored question on stats overflow: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220491/how-does-one-interpret-histograms-given-by-tensorflow-in-tensorboard I don't think I made any bugs but the graphs look weird to me.

Comment: Seems like you have multiple event files, delete all of them except the last

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot interesting. Seems that worked, you know why?

Comment: If you have multiple event files in the same folder, Tensorboard will consider that they belong to the same experience. It will plot the first one, and as the second file restarts from 0 it will join the two runs with a straight line from step 100 to step 0.

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same problem where multiple lines occurred in the Instance tab in tensor board (even I tried your codes and Board service shows the duplicated warning and only present one curve, better than me)

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one graph event per run. Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
```

nevertheless, the solution hold the same as @Olivier Moindrot mentioned, delete the old logs, while sometimes the board may cache some results so you may want to reboot the board services.

The way to make sure we present the newest summary, as the MINIST example shown, is to log at a new folder:

```
if tf.gfile.Exists(FLAGS.summaries_dir):
    tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(FLAGS.summaries_dir)
tf.gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.summaries_dir)
```

Link to full source, with TF version r0.10: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py